# Embedding of fields in matrix rings

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $L/k$ be a field extension of degree $n$. Then it is not difficult to see that $L$, as a $k$-algebra, can be embedded in $M_n(k)$. Now is it ever possible to embed $L$ in $M_{n-1}(k)$?

Comment: If it were the case, then $n$ should divide $(n-1)^2$

Comment: It is not. $L$, as a $k$-algebra, has a single irreducible representation in dimension $n$, so any representation of lower dimension is trivial. (AlexL’s argument is also correct but doesn’t rule out e.g. a field extension of degree $8$ embedding into $M_4$, which this argument does.)

Comment: Thanks AlexL for the nice little argument. And thanks Qiaochu for completing the picture. I was thinking that $M_r(k)$ embeds inside $M_s(k)$ if $r\le s$ which is of course not correct!